# Infinite (or lazy) sampling of a probability distribution

Tags: haskell

I would like to have a function that returns a lazy infinite list of integers following a poisson distribution, with a similar type signature to this one:

```
samplePoisson :: MonadRandom m -> Double -> m [Int]
```

where the `Double` argument is the lambda parameter of the poisson distribution.

I have looked into some libraries (`statistics`, `random-fu`) but none of them provide what i want.

**Edit:**
Yes, both libraries provide functions for generating single values that follow a distribution, which can be easily extended to generate a finite list by using `replicateM`.

Why do I want an infinite list? Because I don't know a priori the number of elements that must be generated.

Let me show an example.
Imagine I have a function that returns the position of the first 1 in a list.

```
findFirst1 :: [Int] -> Int
```

If I had the `samplePoisson` function for generating a lazy list, then I could write:

```
findFirst1 <$> samplePoisson 3.0
```

However, if I am not able to generate a lazy list, then I would have to write a new function with a type signature similar to this one (using the `random-fu` library):

```
findFirst1M :: RVar Int -> RVar Int
```

Hence, I *lose* the function `findFirst1` that I originally had.

I hope I made myself clear this time.

Comment: Are you sure you want a lazy infinite list, as opposed to an `m Int` that you can just call over and over?

Comment: The libraries don't provide poisson distributions? There is an entire (module)[https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.6.2/docs/Data-Random-Distribution-Poisson.html] dedicate to them in random-fu! If by "none of them provide what i want" you mean they don't provide this function exactly, then yes. But a little research effort, like seeing if you can write it yourself, goes a long way.

Comment: `statistics` also supports [generating](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.13.2.3/docs/Statistics-Distribution.html#g:3) from a [Poisson distribution](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.13.2.3/docs/Statistics-Distribution-Poisson.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answers,

Comment: I edited the question to better explain my motivation.